# Adding Multiple Watermark/Overlay Images To An amcharts.com Chart

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, amcharts

I want to add multiple watermark/overlay images to an amcharts.com chart at different locations.

Using the amcharts.com example (here: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/dc7015c33872771cf6e45e7752eaffe3) as a starting point, I tried calling the setOverlayImage function multiple times (once for each image) with different top/left coordinates to vary the positions of the images.  For example:

```
canvas.setOverlayImage(url, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    top: 3,
    left: 3,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
canvas.setOverlayImage(url, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    top: 3,
    left: 1470,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
});
```

Note that the same image (set by url) is used here, but I ultimately want the flexibility to use different images (set by different urls).  However, it only seems to show the image at the position defined in the last calling of setOverlayImage (e.g., top: 3 and left: 1470 in the above example).

Is it possible to add multiple images using setOverlayImage?  If not, can someone suggest an alternative that is compatible with amcharts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can't use `setOverlayImage` for different images on the same canvas, even though the Fabric API documentation doesn't explicitly mention any restriction on this. I managed to make this work by using `fabric.Image.fromURL` and adding the resulting image object through the callback using the canvas object's `add` method:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
  img.set({
    top: 150,
    left: 500
  });
  canvas.add(img);
});

fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
  img.set({
    top: 250,
    left: 700
  });
  canvas.add(img);
});
```

I forked the codepen and made the above changes here: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/aae3c1ed6cda9da3d9914aadddd436fd?editors=0010

Fabric's documentation on the [Image object](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html) lists all the properties you can set through the `set` method to manipulate your images as needed.